# booking.com: do I need to show printed confirmations?

Tags: bookings, hotels, booking.com

When booking hotels via [booking.com](http://www.booking.com/) I used to print the confirmation from booking.com and show this printed paper in the hotel receiption.

But is this necessary? Maybe it's enough to tell my surname and/or show my credit card on which I was booking?

Also, I have booking.com Android application on my mobile phone where I can display my confirmation. Can I just show my confirmation on my mobile phone to the receiptionist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It'll be up to the hotel and sometimes, the discretion of the person on the front desk.

Sure, sometimes your name is enough. Sometimes showing the app is enough (and should be).

But there's that small chance you'll get that one clerk who wants everything done by the book and insists on seeing your printed reservation.  So if you want to avoid hassles, you'll print it out and bring it along.

Comment: All right, so there is no way to find the information on booking.com whether or not some hotel "accepts" app confirmation?

Comment: @PiotrSobczyk not for every hotel, no. However, you could email them, and if you get a written email you could print that out and show said hypothetically annoying hotel clerk. Of course, at that point, you've already printed something out.

Comment: In my experience, 9 times out of 10 they accept your name and ID, but it's that 1 out of 10 which is frustrating :/

Comment: The last time I used booking.com (in León, Mexico), I didn't even have a working data connection to provide the clerk with my reservation number from my phone. She looked it up using my name. It's all very hotel-dependent, as this answer says.

Answer (score 3):

Of course it is safest to print out your confirmation as it eliminates any doubt. I am however a frequent booking.com user (mainly due to their easy cancellation policies) and over the past year I don't remember ever needing more than my name, ID, and credit card to check in.  I just finished a week Europe trip (July 2013) and that was the case at the 4 booking.com hotels at which I stayed.

So looking at it from a cost/benefit analysis, I'd say you can skip printing if the inconvenience is great (no access to printer, running late for a plane, etc.) or if you have a higher tolerance for risk.  My personal approach is the hotel ultimately wants your business, and booking.com generally holds them accountable, so I don't worry too much about not having a confirmation paper.

One caveat:  just because you check in does not necessarily mean you get exactly what you expected. If there is an amenity booking.com said you'd get that isn't given, that would be another case where your own printout would help.

Comment: In case of not having a printer, I have send the confirmation print to my laptop and stored it as a PDF file. If needed I can open it on the screen and even have it printed on the day if needed, but I have never needed it yet. Most of the time when I have a printed confirmation, they do not even look beyond the name, most hotels seem to have the print at hand (or on screen) when you arrive.